# How to connect photos to a google my business listing

Tags: google-maps, photo, google-my-business

Sometimes i browse through google maps properties. I guess all google my business listings (GMB, formerly knows as google places). Then i see photo's:

1. From the owner of the place
2. From people that have been there and added photo's
3. From companies that connected their photo's to the place

I would like to know how to do this 3rd one. I see them a lot. They are not from the owner.

I can't find how to do it. I can add photo's, but then they are uploaded to google and loaded via their domain. Also there is not a place where i can define the url behind the photo & where it should link to.

We have a lot of unique quality photo's that we would like to add. But we would like to see a link to our websie in return.

Examples:
https://www.google.com/maps/place/WEST+GARDA+HOTEL/@45.497498,10.504893,3a,84.6y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1shttps:%2F%2Fcdn.ostrovok.ru%2Ft%2F1024x768%2Fmec%2Fc9%2Fc8%2Fc9c8c38321a18f77a5f0e2f8398af7c4124076fa.jpeg!2e7!3e27!6s%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fproxy%2F1MMOT0KUGv5s2g1596kcoXTFt0N_cUjlgbtFRVvJEgDy63AR6DioBB_63fm2Tg3QE0a66hqWd3HR-UP5TsZJ0sMT3Wd-9hiPeAWDjNjtBc91mbithx8zgY5Oc-g5s9kLvbT4OXbdyvGpBvozx3eDvRvexS0i_g%3Dw203-h135-k-no!7i1000!8i666!4m10!1m2!2m1!1shotel+lake+garda!3m6!1s0x0:0x8ba48549f71b5343!5m1!1s2018-08-05!8m2!3d45.4975038!4d10.5048823

https://www.google.com/maps/place/WEST+GARDA+HOTEL/@45.497498,10.504893,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1shttp:%2F%2Fbstatic.com%2Fimages%2Fhotel%2Fmax1500_watermarked_standard_bluecom%2F0ab%2F0ab0b2c64a0a6ac7fe2e265441de98c11eae236b.jpg!2e7!3e27!6s%2F%2Flh3.googleusercontent.com%2Fproxy%2FL-oUFsuwo1qRMpC_9dEHy7gwxJcG_W971J1XGLCa7nduhsconMfGsgNOXUJ2rgoQLvqh2brHc8Es5q0cSXkmeZ_P-ulE8Ib72hjWC-l8j_czZvkm2zeq0N_0O75TBgsUnpdCr1tgN5dlfx0QEiLBCvMUR4swxXQ%3Dw203-h135-k-no!7i1500!8i1000!4m10!1m2!2m1!1shotel+lake+garda!3m6!1s0x0:0x8ba48549f71b5343!5m1!1s2018-08-05!8m2!3d45.4975038!4d10.5048823

[image]

Comment: Sorry but this question is considered off-topic because of `Web sites out of your control If the question is about another site (such as Gmail or Facebook) and not about your own website`, the question should have been closed or edited before now. The answers provided and comments seem to focus primarily on other sites and not your own website. It's possible that this question can be saved by not requesting or mentioning how your competitors are doing something but rather focus on 'How You Can', it'll attract better answers.

Comment: So i want to know how somebody else is doing a very specific SEO topic it to replicate it on my own site (and others can use it as well for their site...) and it's out of scope :-). Or just frustrated i did not answer your question ;-)

Comment: Sorry but it's not within the scope. Your welcome to use our chat channel to discuss other peoples websites for questions that primary focus on competitors. The only frustration is that I should have closed the question earlier than I did which is my bad. I originally thought it was about how you can do it, but the more we dived in, the more pasting of other competitors and it never become about your site. Anyhow, sorry.